# How to get all existing channels in Hyperledger 1.0 (Node SDK)

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am using the Node SDK with Hyperledger 1.0 and want to check if a channel with a specific name exists. Is there a way to query all existing channels? And is there a way to get a channel by name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot see all available channels, while you can leverage [CSCC](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release/core/scc/cscc/configure.go) (Configuration System Chaincode) GetChannels API to get a list of channels client eligible to. You just need to invoke chaincode named CSCC.

The CSCC is the system chaincode, meaning it inherently built in into peer binary and loaded and "instantiate" during peer startup. You can find details [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/d9c320297bd2a4eff2eb253ce84dc431ef860972/core/scc/importsysccs.go#L31). Considering NodeJS the request will look as following

```
const request = {
  chaincodeId : "cscc",
  txId: 213213123123, // Some random transaction id
  fcn: "GetChannels",
  args: ['']
}
```

BTW you also can do it with peer cli:

```
peer channel list
```

Comment: but I want to know if a channel exists before I instantiate a chaincode , not after. So is there a way to do this from the client node sdk?

Comment: This is a system chaincode it comes built in, no need to instantiate it. Simply invoke it directly before doing anything with chaincode.

Comment: you have a typo "GetChannles" is not "GetChannels"

Comment: This only gets it for each peer right? Not the network?

Comment: It gets this information for endorsing peer only and provide information about channels given endorsing peer has been joined.

Comment: well, otherwise it will compromise security and isolation model multi channel architecture was designed for.