# Hyperledger Fabric query system chaincode using node sdk

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Forgive me if this is a trivial query, It's frustrating to scout the whole internet for every small issue.

My end goal is to get all existing channels. For that, I would have to query CSCC as suggested in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46451026/2503940

However, after creating the request, I would need a client object on which I would call the `queryByChaincode` method. When I try to create a channel instance using `client.newChannel('')`, the code throws an error saying that channel name is mandatory.

Now how do I query an SCC using node sdk without a channel instance?

Answer (score 3):

Sorry you found it hard to find the information you are looking for.  The Fabric Node SDK actually provides a method on the client class which will retrieve all the channels to which a peer belongs:   [client.queryChannels(peer, useAdmin)](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/Client.html#queryChannels__anchor)

Comment: Thanks for the response! But queryChannels returns only the channels in which the peer has joined. In my application, I'm creating a channel with client.createChannel. Calling this method with the channel already created gives an error ({"status":"BAD_REQUEST","info":"error authorizing update: error validating ReadSet: readset expected key [Group]  /Channel/Application at version 0, but got version 1"}). Now, I'd like to get the channels which are already created and in which the peer has not yet joined so that I can avoid this error. Can you tell if there is any way to do that?